# How is Cisco IOS `running-config` output interpreted to generate one-time commands?

Tags: command-line, router

Help me understand how Cisco IOS is configured by explaining how I get from *Configuration* output common in Cisco documentation to the one-time commands used to generate a configuration. They're both heavily documented but not always in the same document.

Here is a link to an early [805 config](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/800/805/software/configuration/guide/advscen.html#wp16990) doc. It has two sections. The first is tables with the headers: Step, Task, Router prompt, Command--every necessary bit of info. The second section is the "Configuration". Here is a link to another [Cisco doc for NAT](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk175/tk15/technologies_configuration_example09186a0080093e51.shtml) with only Configuration section--not helpful for the noob.

---

Also, here is a curious post in some company's [product forum](https://splash.riverbed.com/ideas/1072) describing Cisco device configuration this way,

> This enhancement [the OP is requesting a feature in this forum] would allow for the 
>   creation of templates, offline
>   editing, and offline comparison. This would be consistent with how
>   Cisco devices are managed.

Only I've not found one reference to anything which I would call 'offline' or 'template' editing of Cisco devices. What is this poster refering to? Is there a way to write a 'running-config" to upload and save?

// EDIT: The protocol of `CLI IOS one-time commands -> Running Config -> New Startup Config` is confusing the question. This question is about `Cisco Configuration documentation -> text edit -> New Startup Config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, regarding comments you wrote on my previous answer, i will reformulate.

1. You can copy the `running-config` or the `startup-config` files on
   your PC using `TFTP` command.
2. Once the configuration files are on your PC, you can edit them with
   whatever you want (`Vim`, `Notepad` or any text editor software, as config files are plain text) and do some changes.
3. Then you can upload modified configuration files from your PC to your
   router using `TFTP` also.

These steps (1 and 3) are also used for a Backup/Restore process, but not only ! You can also follow these steps to modify/create an offline config.

Sometimes i do that in my job, mainly when i need to update the configuration for many routers at the same time. This way i can automate the update process, not having to change the configuration manually on each router (have to use `expect` in my scripts to automate).

Also, depending on what you want to achieve, a simple copy/paste from the console to the text editor software would do the trick, as well as recording terminal session output to a text file.

Regards

Comment: Its like Xmas and I get the present I asked for instead of underwear! hahah. This is the answer I will accept, but can you find _one_ reference URL example of step 2?

Comment: I've made a video to show you : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51eLRz7zrf4 (Here i deal with `running-config`. I can make a new one for the `startup-config` if you want). Also, here some references : http://www.cisco.com/image/gif/paws/46741/backup-config.pdf http://web.nmsu.edu/~jbeasley/Cisco_Discovery_4-1/courses/en0500000000/en0505000000/en0505030000/en0505030900/en0505030905/cm5051113765/lab.pdf http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnJyuQPW8dE http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=784Li9arKl8

Comment: Ahaha. I see it is possible. The *RouterGods* Youtube video shows GNS3 (Graphical Network Similator) and Notepad, but the demo is really a shortcut for typing one-time commands; The Cisco doc has only one text file line edit which is **notably** a *gotcha*: "*Open the configuration file with a text editor. Search for and remove any line that starts with "AAA". NOTE: This step is to remove any security commands that can lock you out of the router.*" Sooo, only your video shows _actual_ `startup-config` editing. Kudos! and Accepted.